# Drivers for IBM Motherboard i845G chipset

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to find drivers for IBM motherboard, chipset i845G.

Multimedia Audio Controller is yellowed in Device Manager (XP SP3).

Any help ?

Comment: You have CPU-Z installed.  Click on the Mainboard tab.  What is listed as the Manufacturer?  What is listed as the Model?  I am not asking about the chipset.

Comment: @BonGart, Mainboard Manufacturer: IBM. Model: IBM.

Comment: Is this for some loose motherboard you found in a bin and decided to use?  Is this the motherboard inside of an IBM computer, where there is a model of computer on the case?  Is this for a laptop, or a desktop?

Comment: @BonGart, it's a desktop comp, in a normal i.e. tower case.

Comment: In `Device Manager\Multimedia Audio Controller\Properties\Details\Hardware Ids` - what is PCI Vendor and Product ID? it's VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get your chipset drivers directly from intel.com.  the difference between the 845 the 845e and the 845g are slight improvments over hardware functionality. the 845e adds usb 2.0 support and pentium 4 533mhz FSB speed support. the 845 g adds the same as the 845e but also adds a 3d ghraphics controller and access to the south bridge enabling 6 onboard usb 2.0 ports.
The driver for your chipset will most likely not fix your audio issue. you will need to find the manufacture of the audio chipset and get drivers from their site directly.

Is this a virtual machine or a normal install?

intel chipset link --->  http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/intel845g

Comment: seth buffington, I tried many varsions from intel.com - without success. How can I find the manufacturer of the audio chipset. CPU-Z says: Intel i845g. It's a normal install.

Comment: @Buena If you already tried the ac 97 https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=12170&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%20XP%20Professional and know how to go through the process of testing a few of them using the update drivers capability. The next thing to do would be to look at the audio chip itself and get the numbers off it, than go from there. Avoiding the BS off of "driver" sites alone can take 5 hours :-)

Comment: what is the model number of motherboard. Some Intel based motherboards do not like to update drivers if another is already present, Though I think that is more of a chipset problem with xp. You might have to manually install the driver by unpacking the driver contents to a folder and point the driver updater to the "xxx.inf" . But you want to make sure your using the right driver as to not cause damage.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
SlimDrivers

It will try and find the drivers for you.

Comment: cybernard, I tried Slim Drivers just now, and it downloaded Realtec AC 97 - it doesnt work.